# How could I put one button at the left and the second button at the right in a MAUI application?

Tags: maui

In a MAUI page, I am trying to put one button aligned to the left and the second button to the right. But I am not able to do it.

I am trying this:

```
<StackLayout>
    <HorizontalStackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow">
        <Button HorizontalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarEntradaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronoa.svg"/>

        <Button HorizontalOptions="End"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarSalidaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronob.svg"/>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

With the background, I can see the that the HorizontlStackLayOut fill all the screen from left to right, but the buttons are not in the left.

According to the documentation, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/horizontalstacklayout?view=net-maui-7.0, I think I should to get the expected behavior.

How could I place one button to the left and the second to the right?

EDIT: this is how it looks now:

[image]

EDIT 2: I have tried in this way, as recommended in a comment, using a StackLayout with HorizontalOptions as Fill:

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="Yellow" Orientation="Horizontal"
              VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
    
    <Button HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarEntradaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronoa.svg"/>

    <Button HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarSalidaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronob.svg"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I get the same result.

[image]

If I dont set the orientation of the StackLayout, then I get this result:

[image]

In this case I get one button to the left and another to the right, but I would like to have the same in the same row.

EDIT 3:

This is with a grid:

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Yellow" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarEntradaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronoa.svg"/>

    <Button HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarSalidaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronob.svg"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "but the buttons are not in the left" - so what *does* it look like at the moment? (This is one of the few cases where including an image in a Stack Overflow question really *does* help.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I have added an image how it looks like at this moment. I want the second button to be aligned to the right, to beside the first button.

Comment: The StackLayout doesn’t know to fill the width. It is only wide enough to hold the two buttons. Add `HorizontalOptions=”Fill"` to StackLayout.

Comment: Okay, that makes it much clearer, because the *text* says "but the buttons are not in the left" - whereas it looks to me like the buttons are *both* on the left, and you're not managing to get the one on the *right*. (Given the description, I was expecting both buttons to be on the right - which would have confused me in terms of the XAML, admittedly.)

Comment: I oculd be a bit unclear, yes. Really I want one to the left and the other to the right.

Comment: A Grid would be a better choice of container

Comment: Have you tried a DockLayout? I'd expect that to be straightforward. Set it to fill the width, then set one button with a DockPosition of Left, and one with a DockPosition of Right.

Comment: @JonSkeet in MAUI there is no a DockLayout like in WPF a DockPanel. if not I guess with it, it would be a good solution.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía: It's in the community toolkit: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/layouts/docklayout - I found the docs before suggesting it, so I knew it was available for Maui... but I hadn't clocked that it's not in the main framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `Grid` attempt was a good start, but you are not specifying a `Column` value so both buttons are placed in the same `Column`

```
<Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" BackgroundColor="Yellow" VerticalOptions="Start">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Button Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarEntradaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronoa.svg"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start"
                Command="{Binding ResgistrarSalidaCommand}"
                ImageSource="cronob.svg"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: True, i forgot to set the column to the second button.  Thanks so much.